# Replacing characters in a string array with linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
var file = from line in lines

select (((line => (line == ',' ? '.' : line)) || ((line => (line == ',' ? '.' : line))
```

How do I replace all ',' with '.' AND ';' with ', in C#

Is there any elegant way to do this in linq or do I have to it in two step something like below

```
var file1= from line in lines
           select (line.Replace(',', '.'));

var file2= from line2 in file1
           select (line2.Replace(';', ','));
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just chain two Replace calls? or use RegEx replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Replace` returns a new string object so you can call any string method on the result, including `Replace`:

```
var file1= from line in lines
           select line.Replace(',', '.')
                      .Replace(';', ',')
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use method syntax.  They're completely interchangeable, but LINQ query syntax looks strange here:

```
var file1 = lines.Select(l => l.Replace(',', '.').Replace(';', ','));
```